# Create Shared Access Token with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage returns 403

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a fairly simple method that uses the NEW Storage API to create a SAS and copy a blob from one container to another.

I am trying to use this to Copy blob BETWEEN STORAGE ACCOUNTS. So I have TWo Storage accounts, with the exact same Containers, and I am trying to copy a blob from the Storage Account's Container to another Storage Account's Container.

I don't know if the SDK is built for that, but it seems like it would be a common scenario.

Some additional information:

1. I create the token on the Destination Container. 
   Does that token need to be created on both the source and destination? Does it take time to register the token? Do I need to create it for each request, or only once per token "lifetime"?

I should mention a 403 is an Unauthorized Result http error code.

```
  private static string CreateSharedAccessToken(CloudBlobClient blobClient, string containerName)
    {
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        var blobPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

        // The shared access policy provides read/write access to the container for 10 hours:

        blobPermissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("SolutionPolicy", new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            // To ensure SAS is valid immediately we don’t set start time 
            // so we can avoid failures caused by small clock differences:

            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write |
                          SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        });


        blobPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob; 
        container.SetPermissions(blobPermissions);

        return container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(), "SolutionPolicy");

    }
```

Down the line I use this token to call a copy operation, which returns a 403:

```
  var uri = new Uri(srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + blobToken);
            destBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(uri);
```

My version of Azure.Storage is 2.1.0.2.

Here is the full copy method in case that helps:

```
    private static void CopyBlobs(
        CloudBlobContainer srcContainer, string blobToken,
        CloudBlobContainer destContainer)
    {
        var srcBlobList
            = srcContainer.ListBlobs(string.Empty, true, BlobListingDetails.All); // set to none in prod (4perf)

        //// get the SAS token to use for all blobs 
        //string token = srcContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(
        //    new SharedAccessBlobPolicy(), "SolutionPolicy");

        bool pendingCopy = true;

        foreach (var src in srcBlobList)
        {
            var srcBlob = src as ICloudBlob;

            // Determine BlobType:

            ICloudBlob destBlob;
            if (srcBlob.Properties.BlobType == BlobType.BlockBlob)
            {
                destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(srcBlob.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                destBlob = destContainer.GetPageBlobReference(srcBlob.Name);
            }

            // Determine Copy State:

            if (destBlob.CopyState != null)
            {
                switch (destBlob.CopyState.Status)
                {
                    case CopyStatus.Failed:
                        log.Info(destBlob.CopyState);
                        break;

                    case CopyStatus.Aborted:
                        log.Info(destBlob.CopyState);
                        pendingCopy = true;
                        destBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(destBlob.CopyState.Source);
                        return;

                    case CopyStatus.Pending:
                        log.Info(destBlob.CopyState);
                        pendingCopy = true;
                        break;
                }
            }


            // copy using only Policy ID:
            var uri = new Uri(srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + blobToken);
            destBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(uri);


            //// copy using src blob as SAS
            //var source = new Uri(srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + token);
            //destBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(source);

        }
    }
```

And finally the account and client (vetted) code:

```
       var credentials = new StorageCredentials("BAR", "FOO");
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var sasToken = CreateSharedAccessToken(blobClient, "content");
```

When I use a REST client this seems to work... any ideas?

Comment: How much time is occurring between your creation of the SAS and the use of the URL for the copy?

Comment: It happens instantly; I call the SAS method and miliseconds later call the StartCopyFromBlob() api call. Could it have to do with encoding the uri? I have seen reports that REST clients work but the Azure SDK fails, but have seen no solutions.

Comment: I just realized the problem is that it is going between two different Accounts - I think this means I need creds for both accounts (The Destination and Source)? I'm not sure how the SAS will work across blob content servers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared Access Tokens are not required for this task. I ended up with two accounts and it works fine:

```
        var accountSrc = new CloudStorageAccount(credsSrc, true);
        var accountDest = new CloudStorageAccount(credsSrc, true);

        var blobClientSrc = accountSrc.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var blobClientDest = accountDest.CreateCloudBlobClient();


        // Set permissions on the container.
        var permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions {PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob};
        srcContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);
        destContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);


   //grab the blob
        var sourceBlob = srcContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("FOO");
        var destinationBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("BAR");

        //create a new blob
        destinationBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(sourceBlob);
```

Comment: If you own both accounts then yes, what you've done is fine.  My guess of what was going with the SAS on was clock drift.  When you created the SAS you gave it an expiration, but not a start, which means it started immediately.  The clocks on the servers can drift a bit from each other which means that it is possible the SAS wouldn't work immediately.  The answer is to create the SAS with a start time a few minutes in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Consider also this problem:

```
var uri = new Uri(srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + blobToken);
```

Probably you are calling the "ToString" method of Uri that produce a "Human redable" version of the url. If the blobToken contain special caracters like for example "+" this will cause a token malformed error on the storage server that will refuse to give you the access.

Use this instead:

```
String uri = srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + blobToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both CloudStorageAccount objects point to the same account, copying without a SAS token would work just fine as you also mentioned.

On the other hand, you need either a publicly accessible blob or a SAS token to copy from another account. So what you tried was correct, but you established a container-level access policy, which can take up to 30 seconds to take effect as also documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179391.aspx). During this interval, a SAS token that is associated with the stored access policy will fail with status code 403 (Forbidden), until the access policy becomes active.

One more thing that I would like to point is; when you call Get*BlobReference to create a new blob object, the CopyState property will not be populated until you do a GET/HEAD operation such as FetchAttributes.